# How to forward data to Power Bi from Filebeat Shipper

Tags: elasticsearch, connection, powerbi, filebeat

I have an application that logs user interactions and saves them to a log.json file.

Before, I used Humio as my analytic tool but now I would like to use Power Bi.

I have a data shipper, Filebeat, that forwards the log data (before to Humio).

Now I would like to know, if it it possible to use Filebeat to forward the data to Power Bi.

And if so - how???

This is how my filebeat.yml looked when sending to Humio

```
#======== Filebeat inputs ===========
filebeat.inputs:

- paths:
- path\to\audit_log\*

#-------------------------- Elasticsearch output ------------------------------
output.elasticsearch:

hosts: ["https://cloud.humio.com:443/api/v1/dataspaces/audit_log/ingest/elasticsearch"]
username: myUsername
password: myPassword
```

Do you have any suggestions on how the output.elasticsearch should look like if I would like to use Power Bi?

I have tried to follow the guides: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data

But I need some help - I'm missing some knowlegde or some understanding.

Or a guide that is more near my actual problem.

Thans in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you won´t be able to send the data directly from filebeat to the BI. What you need is some kind of transformation as your BI Dataset JSON stucture is different to the JSON produced by Filebeat.

Have a look on Logstash, it´s part of the elastic stack and Filebeat is made to send the data to Logstash. You´ll just need to apply a minor change in the filebeat.yml

In Logstash you´ll need to configure Extract Transform Load (aka ETL) pipelines in order to recievie (E) all events from the filebeat and transform (T) them to a JSON structure required by the Power BI REST Api (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdataset) and finally issue a HTTP Request (L) to the BI instance.